# Grid pagination breaks in loop

Tags: tapestry

I've observed weird (however most likely it's expected) issue with Tapestry Grid component. Question will come in the end, after longer explanation.

When Grid is used inside of a loop, then pagination stops adding unique grid id to the pagination links. Simple example showing that behaviour

```
<t:numbersgrid max="literal:6"/>
<t:numbersgrid max="literal:6"/>

<t:loop source="numbers" value="number" index="index">
    <t:numbersgrid max="index"/>
</t:loop>
```

First two numbersgrid components, get correct id. Pagination links are following `.../T5sample/about.numbersgrid.grid.pager/2` and `.../about.numbersgrid_0.grid.pager/2` which makes Grid behave correctly.
All grids inside loop get links like `.../about.numbersgrid_1.grid.pager/2` which just does not work :/

Simplifying code (read: in line numbers grid)

```
<t:loop source="numbers" value="number" index="index">
<t:grid source="numbers" row="gridNumber" pagerPosition="bottom" rowsPerPage="2" t:add="number">
     <p:numberCell>
         ${number}
     </p:numberCell>
 </t:grid>
```

does not help either. Effect is quite ... interesting, but that is just a good subject for another topic.

Thing that I don't understand, is why it does not work. It should be possible, but I don't even know where to start searching.

**Question**: Is there any way in which I could make it work. Is it even possible to make a patch for T5 (local change, not even in main repo), that would hallow that to work?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 2):

As you are probably aware, putting a component in a loop means that there's one instance of the component rendered multiple times. This is on of tapestry's [principles](http://tapestry.apache.org/principles.html) of "static structure, dynamic behavior".

You have stumbled upon a limitation of the grid component. It really should accept a context parameter and pass the value to the serverside events (sorting, paging) to support use cases like this.

You can watch [TAP5-2297](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2297) to track the progress. Or better yet, submit a patch with an appropriate test case.

Comment: yeah, that was my best guess, but I hoped that someone had that issue before. I've been checking out code that is out there for grid, but component rendering and passing id of sometype was bit to much for my T5 foo. I'll try to come back to that later as I really want to contribute to the project :)

Comment: the tapestry grid is simply rendering an html table. There's nothing stopping you from rendering your own table without using grid.

Comment: Well there is also a pagination, sorting, and styles in other places of the application. I would have to write a grid with same fix so it's better to just look at the current grid :-) I was able to work around this issue,  but I'll try to come back to it later